# Is it all right to install and run google app engine on your own server?

Tags: google-app-engine

Is it acceptable to install and run google app engine on a server the same way as on a local machine for testing?
I can't personally think of any reasons why not to, but I would imagine there would be some.

Is the best option to host with Google's app servers? What does Udacity do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not really acceptable. The local server is just a "toy" server which mimics what the real server does, but without any optimization or safety. The datastore for example loads everything in memory, and writes everything from memory in a single file.

It's not designed at all to host real applications. Just to be able to test locally without deploying on the real app engine every time. Some services are not available locally either.

And frankly, if the goal is to host locally and not to exploit the elasticity of the app engine infrastructure, there are much better options. Use a real database, and a runtime environment which allows all the classes to be used.

Comment: Is using the Google appserver acceptable for large scale professional websites? I was just reading about how it won't allow files larger than 1mb, so I'm switching to Django. Are this and the rate limits the only catch?

Comment: Building an AppEngine application and deploying it on Google's servers, as intended, is very much acceptable for large-scale professional websites. That is its express intended purpose.

However, using the software -- like the development server -- that comes with the SDK to deploy an AppEngine application to a non-Google server will result in very poor performance, heartache and disaster.

Comment: For the kind of applications that I do, the datastore is really the limiting factor. It doesn't allow the kind of queries that you would expect from a relational database: no join, not more than one inequality clause in a query, limited time on the queries, transactions not spanning more than one entity group, etc. There is a SQL storage engine now, but I've not read about it yet, and AFAIK, the pricing is unknown.

Comment: You can use Cloud SQL from Java and Python apps. See https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/billing for pricing options.

Comment: The App Engine datastore _is_ a "real" database. There are alternative runtimes for App Engine, like typhoonAE and appscale, but I agree that developing explicitly for these platforms is a little strange.

Comment: What I meant is that the local, development, datastore is far from being a real database. The real, appengine datastore is a real database, but, IMHO, not well suited to many kindsof applications.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking whether it's O.K., *for testing purposes*, to run dev_appserver off of a server, I wouldn't advise it. It's not hardened, and it's not going to scale at all well.

If you want to demo an application that's under development, and don't want to deploy to a separate demo/test application (or a demo/test version of your application), it's possible to start dev_appserver with `-a 0.0.0.0`. Assuming your local firewall allows it, and assuming your local machine has routable name on you intranet, this'll let them reach your app from their browser. That's an easy and quick way to get feedback on a UI while it's under development.